# jQuery to replace hard returns in text area with <br/>

Tags: jquery, html

I've read several posts on this subject, but none which properly worked
I'm trying to replace the hard returns in a text area with `<br/>` on button click.

Is this possible? Here is what I have currently:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function () {
$('#button').click(function(){  
$('#y').val().replace(/\r\n/g, "</p><br/><p>&nbsp; ");
var y = '<p>&nbsp; '+$('#y').val()+'</p>';
console.log(y)
});
});
</script>

<TEXTAREA id="y" ROWS="3" COLS="25">
</TEXTAREA>
<br><br>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" id="button">
```

Comment: `$('#y').val()` doesn't get replaced when you call `replace` - you'd need to store the replaced value in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `/\n/g` instead of `/\r\n/g`. You only need to match `\n` not `\n` when preceded by a `\r`. You also need to store the result because `.replace()` *returns* the result (it doesn't apply it to the current value). So:

```
var textWithBreaks = $('#y').val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
var y = '<p>&nbsp; '+textWithbreaks+'</p>';
```

follow-up example: http://jsfiddle.net/qTpm6/

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = $('#y').val().replace(/\n/g, "</p><br/><p>&nbsp; ");
var y = '<p>&nbsp; '+ x +'</p>';
```